# Find interior, closure and boundary of rational number pairs in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the following set:

$$
A=\{(r,r) \mid r \in Q\}
$$
where $Q$ is the set of all rational numbers.

It clear from the definition that the set includes all rational number pairs in $\mathbb{R}^2$, so find interior, closure, and boundary of $A$.

Comment: The diagonal is a closed set containing A, and irrational numbers are dense in R.

Comment: What is diagonal? and what is the significance of dense property of $\mathbb{R}$ here?

Comment: Take a ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$, is it ever contained in $A$? That will tell you what your interior is. With the interior and the closure you should be able to determine the boundary.

Comment: The line y=x.  In every neighborhood, you have both rational and irrational numbers.

Comment: It's no different from the same question about rational points on the real line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interior is empty.
The closure is { (x,x) : x in R }, the diagonal.
Thus the boundary is ...